# How do I create a keyboard shortcut to go to a specific folder?

Tags: finder, keyboard, folders

I have a folder called ~/Documents/Work and I'd like to make the Finder shortcut cmd-shift-W go to that folder, similar to how cmd-shift-H goes to the Home folder (and the equivalent shortcuts for Applications, etc., all under the "Go" menu).

Is it possible to do this? And if so, how can I do it?

Comment: If you're in another application, do you want the shortcut to open a Finder window to the "Work" directory or do you want the shortcut to only work if you're already in Finder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this AppleScript:

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    set workFolder to (POSIX file "/Users/yourname/Documents/Work") as alias
    reveal workFolder
end tell
```

For some reason, the tilde doesn't work in the path, so you have to enter your home folder. Since you want to assign that to a shortcut, download [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/) which enables you to assign shortcuts to AppleScripts.

Hope this helps!

UPDATE:

You can alternatively make an Automator service to run the Applescript.

1. Open Automator and select Service
2. On the left-side menu, select Utilities.
3. In Utilities, drag and drop the "Run Applescript" action into your workflow
4. Copy the applescript above into the "Run Applescript" action
5. Save

Comment: Off topic for this question; but can't applescripts be made into "Services" that can be hot keyed via sys prefs?

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX - I think they can through Automator. I'll look into it and get back to you.

Comment: That's what i was thinking, but idk if Automator has a drag-n'-drop block thingie to implement your own apple script code. I can't check right now b/c i'm not @ home =/

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX - I figured out how to do it

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX - Did that answer your question?

Comment: oh sweet, it does exist! you didn't mention the process of adding a key bind via sys prefs